# Limit of sequence (by definiton)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I have this assignment:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{(-1)^n-3}{n^2}=0$$

I have to prove that limit by definition, but I am stuck with

$$|a_n - 0|< \epsilon$$

Dont know how to deal with that absolute value.

The solution is

$$n_0=\left[\frac{2}{\sqrt\epsilon}\right]+1$$

Comment: Have you tried to see what the numerator is for the first few $n$? That might give you an idea of how to deal with the absolute value. Note that the denominator is always positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$\frac{-2}{n^2}\le\frac{(-1)^n-3}{n^2}\le \frac{-4}{n^2} $$

and then

$$\frac{2}{n^2}\le\left|\frac{(-1)^n-3}{n^2}\right|\le \frac{4}{n^2} $$

therefore

$$\left|\frac{(-1)^n-3}{n^2}\right|\le \frac{4}{n^2} <\epsilon \implies n^2 > \frac{4}{\epsilon} \implies n>\frac{2}{\sqrt\epsilon}$$

therefore it suffices to take

$$n_0=\overbrace{\color{blue}{\left[\frac{2}{\sqrt\epsilon}\right]}}^{\color{red}{\text{integer part}}}+1$$

Comment: can you please explain me the last step? that +1

Comment: Since we need $n>\frac{2}{\sqrt\epsilon}$ we take the integer part of that and add +1.

Comment: And if we have limit of (n)/(n+2)=1 and by definiton the result is [(2/epsilon)-1], why do we dont have to add that +1?

Sorry if it sounds strange but I want to understand math as good as I can. Hate when I have to calculate something mechanically.

Comment: And also when I was calculating this before I asked for help, I wondered about that absolute value. Knew that (4/nˇ2) is higher or equal to prior absolute value, but didnt know I can use it since it could be also (2/nˇ2) for even "n".

Comment: @naruto25 By definition of limit we are looking for $n_0 \in \mathbb N$ but $\frac{2}{\sqrt\epsilon} \in \mathbb R$ therefore we need to extract the integer part and then add $1$. Try with a numerica example: suppose we obtain $n> 100.45$ then we take $n_0=100+1$.

Comment: @naruto25 We are taking an upper bound that is $4/n^2$, we don't need the exact bound but a simple upper which works. For example we also could take $6/n^2$ and the proof works at the same way.

Comment: Ok, so if that sequence is growing and we take eg. epsilon=100 and it says that n>50, it means that every n>50 meets that criteria. So I can taken even n=500 and it fits in that distance from border to "n" member of sequnce?

Comment: @naruto25 We are thinking $\epsilon$ as a small number, for example $\epsilon=.002 \implies \sqrt \epsilon =0.04472...$ and $\frac{2}{\sqrt\epsilon}>44.72...$ then we can take $n_0=45$.

Comment: Ok, so we can take n0=50 as well as n0=45, but 45 is the closest one.

Comment: @naruto25 Exactly!

Answer (score 6):

Given $\epsilon>0 $, we should find $N$ such that if $n\ge N$ then $$|\frac{(-1)^n-3}{n^2}|<\epsilon$$

but

$$|\frac{(-1)^n-3}{n^2}|\le |\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}|+|\frac{3}{n^2}|\le \frac{4}{n^2}$$

thus it is sufficient to find one $N$ such that,

$$n\ge N \;\; \implies \;\; \frac{4}{n^2}<\epsilon$$

or

$$n\ge N \;\;  \implies \;\; n^2 > \frac{4}{\epsilon}$$

or
$$n\ge N \;\; \implies \;\; n > \frac{2}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$$

So, each  $N$  satisfying $N>\frac{2}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$ will work.

the smallest of these $N$ is

$$\lfloor \frac{2}{\sqrt{\epsilon}} \rfloor   +1$$

Comment: So if I had epsilon=1000000 and then it was 0. I do not have null member of that sequence and thus I have to add that 1?

Comment: If $\epsilon=1000000$ then $N=1$

Comment: In general, $\epsilon$ Must be Small. Say if $\epsilon =0.000001$ then $N =?$

Comment: I am still curious why do we have to add that one to that solution.

If I had epsilon=1, then the first member of sequence(n0) from which that limit starts should be 2. And every next member should fit in distance epsilon.

Comment: @naruto25 If it is true for small epsilons, it will be also true for greater epsilons.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, that:

$$\frac{(-1)^n-3}{n^2} \geq \frac{-4}{n^2}$$

And is always negative. So for every $\epsilon$ you can find $N$ ($=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\epsilon}})$, that for every $n>N$ the following holds: $$|\frac{(-1)^n-3}{n^2}| \leq \epsilon$$